# Fatal error "Cannot redeclare template_preprocess_select()" on every attempt to install modules or themes

Tags: 8

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare template_preprocess_select() (previously declared in /Users/ron/Sites/provgmc.dev/core/includes/form.inc:30) in /Users/ron/sites/provgmc.dev/core/includes/form.inc on line 37

This is not an issue with code I've written or altered. I'm just trying to install a theme using the user interface. I tried Bootstrap and Zymphonies, then a simple module or two; they give the same error when trying to install them.

I am using Drupal 8.2.6, running on Mac OS X Sierra, with PHP 5.6.28. I am not using OPCache, and there are no changes from Mac OS pre-installed versions.

I've used Drupal 7 (under El Capitan) in the past, and I have never had any issues like this.

Comment: Can you try using a dev stack that is not the local machine? Like Acquia DevDesktop or MAMP or DrupalVM?

Comment: Try uploading a fresh version of that file, downloaded from Drupal.org. Looks like your file has the function declared twice.

Comment: OK. I installed D8 in a folder in my Linux hosting account and it works as expected. Could it be the PHP distro on my iMac that is causing this problem? How do I proceed? I would really like to do the development of this site locally, on this iMac.

Comment: Did you re-upload the file?

Comment: Are you using template_preprocess_select()? Aren't you supposed to change template_ to your template name?  I'm new to this system too, but just did this same thing.  I dropped that function in my .theme file and it gave me the same error you got.  I had to change template in the function name to my template name.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X should have any of these possible reasons:

- Your site folder name is mixed case
- You cd'd into your site folder name with the wrong case i.e. cd ~/sites/myproject instead of cd ~/Sites/myproject
- Your groups are incorrect (use staff not wheel)
- Drush is using a different version of PHP from MAMP (Check the output of `php --version`.)

If you get a redeclare error running `drush cc all`, check one of the above issues. If `sudo drush cc all` does not produce the error, it could be one of them. In my case, changing the case of my project from ~/Sites/MyProject to ~/Sites/myproject made the issue go away.

For more in-depth discussion, see:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/1305254
- https://www.drupal.org/node/1296594